# VSCode on WSL does not have right-click options features, such as find code reference

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running VSCode on WSL, but unfortunately I lost a lot of functionalities. For example, when I right-click on a function, it only shows:
[image]

There is no option for example to do code referencing.

As comparison, here is the right-click option when I run VSCode on Windows:
[image]

Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Related: [VSCode + remote WSL some functions not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64486820/2745495)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reinstall extensions for the WSL too.

Comment: how to install the extensions in the WSL?

Comment: Better link a screen shot like https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/remote/wsl-tutorial/wsl-installed-extensions.png

Comment: Or a link to the actual VS Code tutorial: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_managing-extensions